# jQuery remove one URL variable

Tags: jquery, url, parameters

I am busy making a web application, which needs to process a lot of erorrs and stuff so i made a jquery ui dialog box. Which shows these errors. The errors are retrieved by database. for example:

when my username/password is incorrect when i try to log in i get redirected to

```
http://domain.com/?do=login&e=login-incorrect
```

the application then know he has to search for the login-incorrect error in the database and show that to the user. Now this all goes very well. Except that when for some reason the user would reload this particular page he wel get the error message again while he doesnt need to get it.

so my plan is to bind some kind of function to the `close` event of the dialog box and redirect the user to the same page bug without the e parameter in the URL. How could i achieve this. I tried all sorts of stuff. But could not get it to work.

What i tried:

bassicly tried getting all possible parameters and stitching those together except for the e parameter. like so:

```
$ERROR = $_GET['e'];
$DO = $_GET['do'];
$P = $_GET['p'];
$C = $_GET['c'];
$T = $_GET['t'];
$ACTION = $_GET['action'];

// URL WITHOUT ERRORS
$needP = "";
$needACTION = "";
$needDO = "";
if($P != ""){
    $needP = "p=".$P."&";
}
if($DO != ""){
    $needDO = "do=".$DO."&";
}
if($ACTION != ""){
    $needACTION = "action=".$ACTION."";
}
$NOERRORURL = $BASEURL."?".$needP.$needDO.$needACTION;
```

But it does not work and its ugly

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
location.href=location.href.replace(/&?e=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "");
```

This will remove all instances of the e parameter from the query string and refresh the page.

Comment: `example.com?e=egg&f=frog` -> `example.com?&f=frog`. The  `?&` is a bit whack.

Comment: `if(location.search.length){
    location.href=location.href.substring(0,location.href.indexOf('?'))+'?'+('&'+location.search.substring(1)).replace(/&e=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i,'').substring(1);
}`

Comment: If it should remove all the occurences, shouldn't it be a global search, like `replace(/&?e=([^&]$|[^&]*)/ig, "");`

Comment: How could this be adapted to remove an arbitrary query parameter? i.e... `removeParameterAndReload("myparameter");`

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it:

```
location.search = location.search.replace(/&e=[^&;]*/,'');
```

That will reload the page like you mention, without the 'e' parameter

---

However, a much better approach is to use a hash instead, like this: `http://domain.com/?do=login#login-incorrect`. Then you can check for the hash when the page loads, and open your error dialog if the `login-incorrect` hash is found:

```
if (location.hash.indexOf('login-incorrect') != -1) {
  // Open your jQuery UI dialog here
}
```

And if they close the dialog, you can simply clear the hash without having to refresh the page:

```
$('.closeErrorDialog').click(function(){
  location.hash = '';
});
```

If you are going to have a lot of these, I recommend Ben Alman's [jQuery hashchange event](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) or the more full-featured [BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) which make your life a lot easier when you are working with hashes.

Comment: This works pretty neat, but what if the user gets an error on the index page? so on the following url. `http://domain.com/?e=login-error` the user will constantly be looped through that error even if he closes the dialog

Comment: But this woukld mean that i have to make 20+ of these manually. right?

Comment: @Toby: the page is never reloaded, so there can't be any loop. And why would you need to make 20+ of these?

Comment: It sounds like the errors are detected server side, so you should really inject the error div/message directly into the page and just use jQuery to make it appear. Passing the error details in a parameter to the client side is twice the work (or in your case, 20 times the work)

Answer (score 4):

```
urlObject = new URL(url);
urlObject.searchParams.delete('myParameter');
```

The Url Object has a searchParams attribute which has the function delete. This will remove **myParameter** from the urlObject. If you want to access your url again, just:

```
url = urlObject.href;
```

Further:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/delete
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams